# Is it possible to visualize non-standard dynamic range (for example, astronomical) images on leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Leaflet supports both image and tile server layers as a mapping layer (along with a few other raster layers).  However, both of these seem to only work with "standard" image types, for example jpeg, png, etc. If I have an image in some higher dynamic range format - specifically, astronomical images in FITS format which have more than 8 bits per channel, is there any way to serve these using leaflet, or do they need to be converted into tiles or images in a more standard format?

Answer (score 1):

As of now (early 2019), there are some [Leaflet plugins for non-standard image formats](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#non-map-base-layers), specifically [Leaflet.TileLayer.IIP](https://github.com/astromatic/Leaflet.TileLayer.IIP) and [Leaflet-IIIF](https://github.com/mejackreed/Leaflet-IIIF). You might be able to transform your images from FITS to one of those formats.

If you're able to slice your image in small tiles, and then generate two (or more) `.png`s or `.jpg`s per each of your FITS image (e.g. one `.png` per each original channel), then you might want to consider a more exotic solution: WebGL through [Leaflet.TileLayer.GL](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL). That Leaflet plugin will allow you to grab pixels from several images at once and combine them with a custom shader function. See Mapbox's [Terrain-RGB tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/) and the TileLayer.GL documentation&demos for more info.

As a side note: Leaflet supports displaying [`.webp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) tiles [if your web browser supports `.webp`](https://caniuse.com/#search=webp).